# Footable Filter on Specific Column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, footable

So far I'm loving Footable!

I have followed the sorting and filtering demo and it is working on my local system. ([Footable Demos](http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/))

One thing that I have come across is:

When using a dropdown to trigger the filter it takes the text value of the drop down and filters all columns that have that matching text.  Sometimes this gives unexpected results because the text could match the middle of some word in one of the columns.

My question is:

Can you specify what column to filter on?  Or a possible alternative would be how to to specify an exact match?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41717755/1630623

Answer (score 0):

Footable searching a all data of the table. It is not supported Specific column based filter.

https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/101

We need to overwrite a plugin for column based search